# How do I configure JpaPersistModule?

Tags: java, guice, guice-persist

Here's my situation. I have a "persistence.xml" with basic JPA properties. I also have several additional properties that I need to inject into JpaPersistModule. These properties (connection strings, etc) come from external components and they are themselves bound by some external guice modules.

This leads to obvious problem - I cannot create an instance of java.util.Properties class to pass to JpaPersistModule because I don't know those properties at the time bindings are configured. What would be the best way to deal with this issue?

P.S. The whole idea of explicitely passing properties into guice module through setter seems strange to me. Man, this is Dependency Injection, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use two injectors:

1. Initialize one injector with the modules that builds the properties
2. Get the properties from the previous injector
3. Use theese properties at the module where you initialize the JpaPersistModule